# Heatmap on Moving People

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing a code to visualize motion path and coverage area that people walking in street or shopping center to show the more interesting place for people with heatmap function.

I grab the video frame and convert to gray. then extracted Height and width of the frame. After that create a mask by background subtraction algorithm and applying on the frame. Next I applied np.zeros on the frame and create the accumulator frame and add the background image with the accumulator and the converted frame from 0-1 values between 0-255 by 'cv2.convertScaleAbs' and then implemented thresholding and apply colormap_jet and finally I added the result of threshold frame with RGB color frame.

```
mask = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while True:

    ret,frame1 = vs.read()

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    (height,width) = frame.shape[:2]

    sub = mask.apply(frame,None,0.01)

    accumulator = np.zeros((height,width), dtype = np.float)
    sub = sub + accumulator

    ab = cv2.convertScaleAbs(255-np.array(sub,'uint8'))

    ret, acc_thresh = cv2.threshold(ab, ab.mean(),255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
    acc_col = cv2.applyColorMap(acc_thresh, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

    backg = cv2.addWeighted(np.array(acc_col,'uint8'),0.55,frame1,0.55,0)

    cv2.imshow("frame11",backg)
```

But I can not get correct result when I run my code. I want to change the color of an area that people moving a lot.

Comment: I attempted to correct your formatting, but I am not sure whether you intended the last line to be inside the `while True` loop. Please indent that line if it should be within the loop.

Comment: Hi Mr John, the last line includes the while True.

Comment: "I want to change the color of an area that people moving a lot.": what exactly do you want? Can you illustrate with a picture?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-VLHzilz30. I want something like this, here car moving and the colormap change and I want to implement this for people.

Comment: Did you try the [source-code](https://github.com/Muhamob/Simple-Python-heatmap/blob/master/test.py) of the video?

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem has been solved. by checked the source-code.